# How can I execute command line output in windows without having to generate a bat file?

Tags: windows, shell, pipe

I did a little script to pull the latest of all my subrepos in Mercurial (without updating them) for a very particular experiment (integrating with another VCS whose repo I had to break in different subrepos) that requires all subrepos in sync.

For this, a first step is the following command:

```
cat .hgsubstate|sed -r s:^\w+\s(.*):\1:g|sed -r s:(.*):'hg pull -R \1 perforce':g
```

That gives me as output all the commands I have to execute line by line, however I'm in windows and there is no eval to pipe them to (I have cygwin):

```
hg pull -R apps/canservice perforce
hg pull -R apps/hmi perforce
hg pull -R apps/lua perforce
```

I don't want to have to generate a bat file, execute it and then delete it, so, is there any alternative for doing this in a single blow?

Comment: @svnpenn Yup, that is correct, but using the normal command line from Windows, not bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me in the past

```sh
foo | bar | cmd.exe
```

Comment: The .exe extension is unnecessary, this did it though